# Select specific text from sql query

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i need some help. This is my code (it's missing the db connect on purpose but it's working)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
           INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id 
        WHERE  wp_posts.post_type='ait-job-offer' 
           AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
           AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='_ait-job-offer_offer-data'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);


$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument('1.0' , 'iso-8859-1' ); 
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('xml');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $xml->startElement('job');

    $xml->startElement("jobs");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($row['post_name']));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("id");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($row['ID']));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("link");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($row['guid']));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("name");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($row['post_title']));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("region");
    $xml->writeRaw('Portugal');
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("salary");
    $xml->writeRaw(' ');
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("company");
    $xml->writeRaw('M21Rh - Empresa de Trabalho Temporário, Lda');
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("company_url");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode('http://www.m21rh.pt/empresa/quem-somos/'));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("description");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode(strip_tags($row['post_content'],'')));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("expire");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($row['meta_value']));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->startElement("updated");
    $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($row['post_date']));
    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->endElement();
}


$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
?>
```

And this is the results this code gives

```
<job>
<jobs>consultoresformadores-para-zona-de-lisboa</jobs>
<id>2320</id>
<link>http://www.m21rh.com/?post_type=ait-job-offer&p=2320</link>
<name>Colaborador Front Office para a zona de Sines </name>
<region>Portugal</region>
<salary> </salary>
<company>M21Rh - Empresa de Trabalho Temporário, Lda</company>
<company_url>http://www.m21rh.pt/empresa/quem-somos/</company_url>
<description>A  M21Rh - Empresa de Trabalho Temporário, Lda., recruta para empresa sua Cliente , Colaborador Front Office para a zona de Sines.

Perfil:

- Responsável;

- Pontual;

- Dinâmico.

Requisitos:

- Boa Apresentação;

-12º Ano (Mínimo Obrigatório);

-Experiência em Windows Office (Obrigatório);

- Carta de Condução e Transporte Próprio;

- Residente na zona de Sines;

- Fácil dicção;

- Disponibilidade de Horários e de deslocações para Espanha;

- Experiência na área Comercial;

- Experiência em Recursos Humanos;

- Experiência em Recrutamento e Seleção;

- Domínio de Espanhol e Inglês;

Oferecemos: Vencimento base compatível com a função.
Responder a esta oferta
[si-contact-form form='4']</description>
<expire>a:6:{s:6:"skills";s:0:"";s:9:"validFrom";s:16:"Thu, 22 May 2014";s:7:"validTo";s:16:"Mon, 30 Jun 2014";s:11:"contactName";s:0:"";s:11:"contactMail";s:0:"";s:12:"contactPhone";s:9:"265238165";}</expire>
<updated>2014-03-12 17:06:37</updated>
</job>
```

I need some help.
In the expire tag ,, i just need a tiny bit of information from there.

I always get results like

```
a:6:{s:6:"skills";s:0:"";s:9:"validFrom";s:16:"Thu, 22 May 2014";s:7:"validTo";s:16:"Mon, 30 Jun 2014";s:11:"contactName";s:0:"";s:11:"contactMail";s:0:"";s:12:"contactPhone";s:9:"265238165";}
```

But i just need to use the date after validTo

"validTo";s:16:"Mon, 30 Jun 2014"

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data is in serialized form.. so first unserialize your data then you can use.

use serialize() and unserialize() function

like

```
$str = serialize($array);

$arr = unserialize($strenc)
```

;

Use this...at expire

```
$strval = unserialize(utf8_encode($row['meta_value']) );
 $xml->writeRaw($strval[validTo]);
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm really really new at php. I didn't even understand what that means,anyway,thanks for replying

Comment: Whatever result your are getting..take it in a php variable and use unserialize(thatstring) method

Comment: Yea but I hope you changed the variable name to validTo as that is what you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

that format is serialized() try to unserialized() your text.

Comment: Sorry, i'm really really new at php. I dont even understand what you meant,still,thanks for your reply

Comment: try this..........

$str = 'a:6:{s:6:"skills";s:0:"";s:9:"validFrom";s:16:"Thu, 22 May 2014";s:7:"validTo";s:16:"Mon, 30 Jun 2014";s:11:"contactName";s:0:"";s:11:"contactMail";s:0:"";s:12:"contactPhone";s:9:"265238165";}';
$arr=unserialize($str); 

echo $arr['validTo'];

OUTPUT: "Mon, 30 Jun 2014"

Comment: okay try to insert this in your xml_writer() under 

 $xml->startElement("expire");
  $meta_value = unserialize($row['meta_value']);
  $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($meta_value['validTo']));
  $xml->endElement();

Answer (score 0):

The data held in the column called 'meta_value' has been created using the `serialize()` function. This takes an array and  converts it into a string so it can be saved to the database in a single column, it can then be unserialized using the `unserialize()` to convert it back to a PHP array.

So you need to turn it back into an array and then get the piece of data you are interested in.

So try this.

```
$ar = unserialize($row['meta_value']);
$validTo = $ar['validTo'];

$xml->startElement("expire");
$xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode($validTo));
$xml->endElement();
```